# ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023 Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Ошибка выскакивает при обращении к задеплоиному проекту, попробовал уже несколько проектов(думал может это проблема с моим проектом), всегда выскакивает ошибка:

```
10:48:36,718 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005023: Exception handling request to /helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [1074] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:142)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:163)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:248)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:154)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:120)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:158)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:179)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2028)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Channels.java:152)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:290)
    at io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.writeBuffer(BlockingSenderImpl.java:190)
    at io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.writeBuffer(BlockingSenderImpl.java:183)
    at io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.send(BlockingSenderImpl.java:59)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResource$1ServerTask.run(PathResource.java:184)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResource.serveImpl(PathResource.java:253)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResource.serve(PathResource.java:111)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletResource.serve(ServletResource.java:96)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachedResource.serve(CachedResource.java:168)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.serveFileBlocking(DefaultServlet.java:345)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:185)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

я ещё ни разу не пользовался wildfly, подскажите что не так делаю?
Проект деплоит idea.Но пробовал я и сам ручками закидывал его в
standalone\deployments - результат всегда один и тот же.
Помогите